# Unable to add JSP files into Project

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-wtp

Here is a picture of my environment and I am unable to create JSP files, I am not sure what I am missing let me know what I can answer to get a resolution. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It looks like what I needed to do after some research was to go to help - install New software - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno  and select WEB,XML drop down and select anything dealing with eclipse and web and then the file extensions where available.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is having this issue with Sring Starter Project in Spring Tool Suite 4:

```
Help -> Install New Software -> WorkWith Spring Tool Suite 4
```

Scroll to bottom  and select :

```
Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using the *standard* version of eclipse. (As you are using the default "Java" perspective, not "Java EE".)

The solution would be to download the version of eclipse that has Java EE support. This version will enable you to create Servlets, JSPs and many more through wizards (that's what you seem to be looking for).

Get the current version (Juno SR2) of *Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers* here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2 (choose the version according to your system in a box called *Download Links* at the right-side of the page).

The wizard will be available then. Also, don't forget to change the perspective to Java EE (in a button at the top of the right-hand side of you eclipse), as it will show your web projects in a better organized way.

Comment: thank you @acdcjunior! updated link - https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Comment: what i did was - on the Eclipse IDE -> go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> write 'jsp' on searchbox and hit enter -> installed 'Eclipse Java Enterprise Developer Tools 3.16' -> Eclipse restarted